# crear jar con eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy creando un .jar desde eclipse neon.
Al ejecutar el programa desde el mismo eclipse corre sin problemas.
Pero al exportar y crear el jar me da un error con el main

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien ha pasado por lo mismo y como lo ha solucionado?

Comment: De casualidad lees tu archivo de propiedades desde la ruta absoluta? es decir completa desde el c:\? debes leerlo como recurso, pon el código de cómo lees el archivo y cómo queda tu empaquetado

Comment: Hola, leo desde una clase constantes, la linea donde ubico las propiedades es la siguiente: public static String CONFIG_FILE = "trabajo" + File.separator + "proyecto" + File.separator + "propiedades" + File.separator + "Java.properties";